# deploying a wcf service to IIS

Tags: wcf, iis

I created a WCF Services Application in c# in Visual Studio 2017. It is a very basic service as I am in the early design stages. My development machine and the web server (IIS 2008) are  not on the same network.  My question how to deploy it? Should I publish it to the file system and copy it to the server? After I get to the server what is the next step.

Comment: See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS